# Python: How to open a multisheet .xslx file (with formatting) and edit a few cells and save it as another .xlsx file

Tags: python, excel

I have tried using openpyxl but it seems to fail when I am saving the file (http://pastebin.com/VU5LTajH) and I cannot find any info about the problem.

Any other modules that let you read edit and save an .xlsx file while retaining the style and formatting of the original file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use win32com library (I assume that you're working on Windows) and dispatch excel application via COM.
Inside, you can use every method that is available in VBA (so that's good to work with [Object model reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068%28v=office.15%29.aspx) as documentation).

Below simplified example how I use it.

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch ("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
if isinstance(worksheetName, str):
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(worksheetName)
else: #assume that worksheetName is number
    sheet = workbook.Worksheets[worksheetName]

def getRange(worksheet, address):
    return worksheet.Range(address)

def getValue(range_):
    """Returns values from specified range, as tuple of tuples (even if range
    is single row) or single value if range is one cell"""
    return range_.Value2

def setValue(range_, values):
    range_.Value2 = values
```

As I see workbook object has method `SaveAs`, so I'd use it to save it as another file after changing cells value, like this:

```
workbook.SaveAs("newFilename")
```